# How can I validate HTML5 directly in Vim?

Tags: validation, html, vim

Of course it is possible to use the good old online tools like the W3C Validator, but I think it would be more efficient to validate in Vim directly.

I tried the built-in HTML validation of a plugin called "Syntastic", which used HTML Tidy by default.
Although it seems to work, I found out that HTML Tidy doesn't really support HTML5 yet and the solution looks more like a hack. Please let me know if I'm wrong.

However I also found a rather old article about using an online service in Vim:

http://blog.whatwg.org/vim-checker

Although it didn't work for me so far, I think it is possible to make it work with Syntastic.

Last but not least, I checked the internet for some command line apps and this is all I found:

http://about.validator.nu/html5check.py

A script that uploads a file to the same online service and outputs errors to the commandline.

Does anybody of you know whether I can at least make this script work together with syntastic or Vim in general? Or does anybody know another solution? A step by step guide would be really cool.

thx in advance

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: a better solution for me was the following:

Download this script, make it executeable and put it into your path.

http://about.validator.nu/html5check.py

Then add this to you vimrc:

```
"check html
map ,h5 :!html5check %<CR>
```

You don't need to read the rest.

---

Wow, suddenly it worked and I wondered myself why not right away...

Here is my solution for Vim users like me:

1. Install Syntastic
2. Navigate to `[Syntastic plugin folder]/syntax_checkers/html.vim`
3. Comment out the original `"let makeprg=..."` and `"let errorformat=..."`
4. Add the following snippet

   `let makeprg="html5check ".shellescape(expand('%'))`

   `let errorformat='%m'`

As you might guess it calls a commandline app to check the code.

4. In order to use it, download the following file and make sure it is executeable:

   http://about.validator.nu/html5check.py
5. I removed the extension and pasted it to the other commandline apps I have in `opt/local/bin`. In your case it might be a different location.

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: i have to add that it doesn't seem to be really stable and looks weird. If somebody knows a better solution let me know.

Comment: The Python script sends the HTML code to http://html5.validator.nu/, right? What do you do when/if you are offline? (Have you thought about installing the validator locally and modifying the script so the HTML code gets sent to the local validator service?)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple plugin that looks like it does the same thing.

https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/vim-htmlvalidator

Answer (score 1):

ALE is the preferred lint engine for Vim if you're into IDE-like Vim-experience:

https://github.com/w0rp/ale#1-supported-languages-and-tools

Look under HTML - install one of these and what you get is asynchronous as-you-type HTML-validation.